# Writing string to ostream

Tags: c++, gcc

When I try to compile the code below (in a Qt 4.8 using llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1), I get the following error:

```
../GLWidget.cpp:24:   instantiated from here
../GLWidget.cpp:24: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
```

What does this error mean, and what should I do to fix it?

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void testOStream(){
    filebuf fb;
    fb.open ("test.txt",ios::out);
    std::ostream os(&fb);
    std::string test("test");
    os << test; // This line has the problem
    fb.close();
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine on [ideone](http://ideone.com/oqZcBI)

Comment: This should have compiled, but try adding `#include <ostream>`.

Comment: Looks like this is fairly common problem if you are on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, try adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` as a compile flag if you are

Comment: @user93353: Interestingly, before C++11, `iostream` was not required to `#include <ostream>`.

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00). Try @user93353's suggestion.

Comment: Hmm.  That `operator<<` is supposed to be in `<string>`, not `<ostream>` (for both C++03 and C++11).  So this is definitely a compiler bug.

Comment: @aschepler I think the compiler is complaining about line `std::ostream os(&fb);` - where does `string` & `<<` come into the picture.

Comment: The error was on line `os << test;` and complains about function `std::operator<<`.

Comment: You do realize that it would be easier to use `std::ofstream`.

Comment: @ChadCampbell You are right :) Could you post your comment as an answer, then I can close the question. (I tried running the new Qt 5.0 where everything works fine - Qt 5.0 uses -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 and Qt 4.8 uses -mmacosx-version-min=10.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChadCambell pointed out, the problem turned out to be that Qt 4.8 uses -mmacosx-version-min=10.5, but should have been -mmacosx-version-min=10.7

I found some more use info of the problem here:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19106/P15

Updating to Qt 5.0 also solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a C++ version prior C++11, you may want to add `#include <ostream>` to your program.

Only with C++11 and later `<iostream>` is required to `#include <ostream>`.

#### Header `<iostream>` synopsis

C++2003:

> ```
> namespace std {
>    extern istream cin;
>    extern ostream cout;
>    extern ostream cerr;
>    extern ostream clog;
>
>    extern wistream wcin;
>    extern wostream wcout;
>    extern wostream wcerr;
>    extern wostream wclog;
> ```
>
> }

C++2011:

> ```
> #include <ios>
> #include <streambuf>
> #include <istream>
> #include <ostream>
>
> namespace std {
>     extern istream cin;
>     extern ostream cout;
>     extern ostream cerr;
>     extern ostream clog;
>
>     extern wistream wcin;
>     extern wostream wcout;
>     extern wostream wcerr;
>     extern wostream wclog;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `#include <ostream>`. Earlier than C++11, `<ostream>` is not guaranteed to be included by `<iostream>`. The reason the definition of `os` was fine may be because it's usually implementation defined which standard library headers include other standard library headers (except where specified). With your implementation, `<iostream>` may have included a definition of `std::ostream`, but not the functions that go with it. However, it *should* have included everything if you're compiling C++11.

Comment: But `<iostream>` is required to include `<ostream>`.

Comment: Yeah, I checked one standard and didn't realize it was a change.